# Ef Core HasConversion not working using CosmosDb provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, ef-core-3.1

I'm using Ef Core with CosmosDb provider and I want to use strongly typed Id for my Entities but my code does not work correctly. detail:

Domain:

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    public CustomerId Id { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerId : TypedId<string>
{
    public CustomerId(string value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
public class TypedId<TKey>
{
    public TKey Value { get; }
    protected TypedId(TKey value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Config:

```
class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.HasPartitionKey(x => x.PartitionKey);

        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ToJsonProperty("id");

        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new CustomerId((x)));
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.PartitionKey).ToJsonProperty("partitionKey");
        builder.Property(x => x.FirstName).ToJsonProperty("firstName");

        builder.Property(x => x.DocumentType).ToJsonProperty("documentType");
        builder.HasDiscriminator(x => x.DocumentType);
    }
}
```

after saving an entity with

> id = new CustomerId(someGuid.ToString())

this is the result, but I expect a GUID as id:

```
{
   "id": "Customer|Domain.Customers.CustomerId",
   "documentType": "CustomerProfile",
   "firstName": "Moji",
   "partitionKey": "100-2",
   "_rid": "8L5mAKVMiToMAAAAAAAAAA==",
   "_self": "dbs/8L5mAA==/colls/8L5mAKVMiTo=/docs/8L5mAKVMiToMAAAAAAAAAA==/",
   "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-b5ac-bcf438d801d6\"",
   "_attachments": "attachments/",
   "_ts": 1604825656
}
```

does anyone have an idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: What is the `TypedId` generic there?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras I've put the code in the question.

Comment: Pretty sure this is confusing the Cosmos SDK. Why not just make your id a string and put a new guid in the setter?

Answer (score 2):

Convert `datatype` of `Id` from `CustomerId` to `string` and save the document **without adding any value for Id**:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Cosmos DB will **automatically** create a GUID for you.

Comment: Does this answer help you @M.Khooryani?